# Filtering a ManyToMany field to User insida a form in Django

Tags: django

I've got a custom Model called `Group` with two `ManyToMany` fields called `admins` and `members` (both to the default `User` model). I've built a form to edit the administrators:

```
class AddAdminsForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = (
            'admins',
        )
```

Now I want to filter the selection options inside the `admins` field based on whether it is present in the `members` field. What would be the best way to achieve that? By entirely changing my members/admins architecture or by somehow messing with the `__init__` method inside the form class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to check this solution right now but maybe you can:

```
....
in your function
form.fields['admins'].queryset  = Members.objects.all()
```